# Траектория движения пули c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, разработка-игр

Необходимо реализовать движение пули во всех направлениях: вверх, вниз, врпаво, влево. Вправо и влево все работает, а вот при выстреливании вверх и вниз пуля остается на месте. Никак не могу разобраться, в чем ошибка. Код прилагаю ниже.

```
class Bullet
{
    public string direction;
    public int bulletLeft;
    public int bulletTop;

    private int speed = 20;
    private PictureBox bullet = new PictureBox();
    public Timer bulletTimer = new Timer();

    public void MakeBullet(Form form)
    {
        bullet.BackColor = Color.White;
        bullet.Size = new Size(5, 5);
        bullet.Tag = "bullet";
        bullet.Left = bulletLeft;
        bullet.Top = bulletTop;
        bullet.BringToFront();

        form.Controls.Add(bullet);

        bulletTimer.Interval = speed;
        bulletTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(BulletTimerEvent);
        bulletTimer.Start();
    }
    private void BulletTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bullet movement
        if (direction == "left")
        {
            bullet.Left -= speed;
        }
        if (direction == "right")
        {
            bullet.Left += speed;
        }
        if (direction == "top")
        {
            bullet.Top -= speed;
        }
        if (direction == "down")
        {
            bullet.Top += speed;
        }

        //dispose bullet
        if (bullet.Left < 10 || bullet.Left > 860 || bullet.Top < 10 || bullet.Top > 900)
        {
            bulletTimer.Stop();
            bulletTimer.Dispose();
            bullet.Dispose();
            bulletTimer = null;
            bullet = null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, вызывающий логику этого класса.